# SetState in an array with React spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spread-syntax

I have a value in my react state that looks like so:

```
appointmentsData = {
  "05-01-2018": [
    {
      id: "1",
      friendly: "9:00am - 10:00am",
      openDateTime: "9:00am",
      closeDateTime: "10:00am"
    }
  ]
};
```

I have a new piece of data:

```
const newAppt = {"06-30-2018":[]}
```

How do I addon to my data in the state? I tried

```
this.setState({ ...this.state.appointmentsData, ...newAppt});
```

It seems to no be adding onto state though. I get back the same value in the render as before (appointmentData before spread). The newAppt never gets added to the state.

I am trying to get my states desired output to be:

```
appointmentsData = {
  "05-01-2018": [
    {
      id: "1",
      friendly: "9:00am - 10:00am",
      openDateTime: "9:00am",
      closeDateTime: "10:00am"
    }
  ],
  "06-30-2018": []
};
```

Comment: What does your state look like exactly? Is object-rest-spread supported in your browser (or are you using a babel plugin for it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use spread operator on `newAppt`. Just go with:
`this.setState({ ...this.state.appointmentsData, newAppt});`. It seems to me that the spread operator on `newAppt` is not getting any data for the `const`.

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to do it, really. Here's one:

```
this.setState(prevState => (
  {appointmentsData: {...prevState.appointmentsData}, newAppt}
));
```

Though your approach should work too, if you just add the `appointmentsData:` first. Like so:

```
this.setState({appointmentsData: {...this.state.appointmentsData, ...newAppt}});
```

This will spread all the previous values into a new object, plus the one you want to add.

I personally always use the functional way of setting the state when the new one depends on a previous state value, but your way is fine here too.